# The simplest nontrivial (unstable) integral cohomology operation

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, cohomology-operations

By an integral cohomology operation I mean a natural transformation $H^i(X, \mathbb{Z}) \times H^j(X, \mathbb{Z}) \times ... \to H^k(X, \mathbb{Z})$, where we restrict $X$ to some nice category of topological spaces such that integral cohomology $H^n(-, \mathbb{Z})$ is represented by the Eilenberg-MacLane spaces $K(\mathbb{Z}, n)$. The Yoneda lemma shows that such operations are in natural bijection with elements of $H^k(K(\mathbb{Z}, i) \times K(\mathbb{Z}, j) \times ... , \mathbb{Z})$.

Altogether, these cohomology operations determine a (multisorted) [Lawvere theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lawvere_theory). There is an obvious subtheory of this theory generated by zero, negation, addition, the cup product, and composition. Based on the table in [this paper](http://www.mathnet.or.kr/mathnet/thesis_file/05_B08-327.pdf), it looks like the simplest integral cohomology operation not in this obvious subtheory is a cohomology operation $H^3(X, \mathbb{Z}) \to H^8(X, \mathbb{Z})$ coming from the generator of $H^8(K(\mathbb{Z}, 3), \mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$, but I don't know enough algebraic topology to extract an explicit description of this cohomology operation from the paper.

So: what is this cohomology operation? Where does it come from? What can you do with it? (I know there are some cohomology operations coming from the $\text{Tor}$ terms in the Künneth formula; is this one of them?)

Comment: (somewhat) related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/6377/why-does-one-think-to-steenrod-squares-and-powers

Comment: follow-up: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/429976/why-massey-cube-of-an-odd-element-lies-in-3-torsion

Comment: (different) follow-up @ MO: [From calculation of $H^\bullet(K(\pi;n))$ to explicit construction of operations](http://mathoverflow.net/q/135303/1556)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Suppose $\alpha$ is an integral $3$-cocycle on a space $X$. Then $2\alpha\cup\alpha$ is a coboundary, because the cup product is graded-commutative, and there exists a $5$-cochain $\beta$ such that $\mathrm d\beta=2\alpha\cup\alpha$. One can easily check that $\alpha\cup\beta+\beta\cup\alpha$ is an $8$-cocycle. I think that the class of this cocycle does not depend on the choice of $\beta$, so we get a well defined mapping $H^3\to H^8$. This map is natural because there is a natural proof that the cup product is graded-commutative, so we $\beta$ depends naturally on $\alpha$.

This gives an operation :-)

Comment: $\alpha\beta=-\beta\alpha$, so your operation seems to be zero, no?

Comment: That equality holds in *cohomology*, not on the level of (singular) cocycles. Notice that $\beta$ is not even a cocycle.

Comment: This is so obvious that it had to be done ages ago :-) Something very similar was studied by Kraines [here](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1966-124-03/S0002-9947-1966-0202136-1/home.html) He shows that his is zero over the rationals, and non-trivial over odd primes (it is then given by Bocksteins and reduced powers) He does not say anything about integralcoefficients, afaict.

Comment: Oh, you're right. (What anti-commutativity actually implies is that the definition doesn't depend on choice of $\beta$.)

Comment: (I'm upvoting this, but the question why this operation is nontrivial still remains...)

Comment: @mariano how does this definition occur to you?

Comment: @user17786, if $x$, $y$, $z$ are classes such that $xy=0=yz$, then the product $xyz$ is zero for «two reasons». This observation is used to construct a secondary operation called the Massey triple product (this is explained more or less in Wikipedia) I started with this and tried to make it work better than usual in our case (triple products have an indeterminancy, but it disappears in out case magically)

Comment: Interesting! Does this Massey product line of reasoning suggest a reason why this operation ought to land in $3$-torsion?

Comment: If this is non-zero, the example should be on $K(Z,3)$, mapping the identity mapping in $H^3(K(Z,3))$ to a non-zero element of $H^8(K(Z,3))$. This should work already on sufficiently good approximations to the E-M space, like $(S^3)^n/\Sigma_n$ (with $n=3$, probably)...

Comment: This operation is presumably the same as $H^3(X,\mathbb{Z}) \to H^3(X,\mathbb{Z}/3) \xrightarrow{P^1} H^7(X,\mathbb{Z}/3) \to H^8(X,\mathbb{Z})$, where $P^1$ is the first Steenrod operation, and the first and last maps are from the coefficient sequence for $0\to \mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}/3\to 0$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I suspect it's something like Jacobi identity. (Notice that the operation is $P(\alpha)=[\alpha,\beta]$ and $d\beta=[\alpha,\alpha]$, where $[-,-]$ is the supercommutator...)

Comment: @GrigoryM, triple products are indeed closely related to the Jacobi identity; this is explained in McCleary's book spectral sequences, iirc.

Comment: @CharlesRezk, that's the sort of thing Kraines gets for Massey powers $\langle a,\dots,a\rangle$, in fact.